# Is deception by omission ever allowed?

Tags: mussar-ethics

### Background

Assume the following facts:

- One person (***A***) is aware another person (***B***) believes something is true that is not true.
- ***A*** did not cause ***B***'s misplaced belief.

## Questions

> 1. Does ***A*** have any obligation to affirmatively attempt to correct ***B***'s misunderstanding? Or is it permissible to "deceive by omission" (by remaining silent)? *I **assume** the answer to this question is that remaining silent is **acceptable**; otherwise, we would be obligated to comment on a large swath of the internet and elsewhere as @Yishai [points out in this piece of satirical humor](http://xkcd.com/386). Hence, the necessity of the two following related questions...*
> 2. Does the analysis change if ***A*** **benefits** by remaining silent?
> 3. Does the analysis change if ***B*** (or anyone else) suffers some **loss** resulting from ***A*** remaining silent?

Comment: Thanks for the reworked question.  For future reference, it is generally better to edit an existing question than to delete and re-ask.  Thanks.

Comment: Consider the way Hashem spoke to Avraham about Sarah laughing ("behold I am old"). That seems to imply an answer to your question.

Comment: What about the whole story with Yaakov and the Bracha?  Even according to the medrash that Yaakov didn't actually lie, he certainly misled Yitzchak and Eisav arguably suffered a loss.

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/11/truth-and-lies/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is permissible to omit or otherwise present the truth misleadingly for reasons of tact or to maintain peace. As in the lyrics of the famous wedding song "keitzad meraqdim".

The gemara asks (Keusvos 16b), "How does one celebrate before the bride?" Beis Shammai answer (17a) that one should describe the bride as she is. Beis Hillel tell us to call her a "kalah na'ah vachasudah - a beautiful and kind bride". Rashi (ad loc) says, because (we assume) that is how she appears in her groom's eyes, even if it's not exactly "as she is" in our own opinion.

(Discussions about how appropriate that is for lyrics to be sung at weddings is tangential to this answer.)

The gemara (Yevamos 65b) finds two sources in Bereishis. The first is when G-d Himself omits part of the story He tells Avraham. Avraham wonders why Sarah is laughing at the news that they would have a son. Hashem tells him about Sarah's astonishment given her own age, and omits the bit where she mentions her husband's.

A case at the end of Bereishis goes further... When Yaaqov died and the brothers who wronged Yosef were afraid that he might now mete out their punishment, they tell Yosef that Yaaqov on his deathbed told them to relay his plea that he forgive them.

And the third gemara (Bava Metzi'ah 23b-24a) usually quoted on this topic:

> Rabbi Yehudah said in Shemuel's name: In these three matters it is the practice of our rabbis to distort their words: In matters of a tractate [claiming modestly than you don't know something you do], a bed [when saying something would end up revealing details of one's sexual life], and hospitality [so as not to insult a host -- "the food was great!" or about the host, to avoid him being overrun with ingracious guests].

Comment: You asked: Is deception by omission ever allowed?

I would think that is unquestionably answered by discussing three talmudic sources that discusses when deception is allowed through lying and through incomplete truths -- the very omission you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

Other contexts of sins of omission: if a woman has committed adultery, she is now prohibited to her husband. What if I become aware of her adultery, but her husband doesn't know. Am I obligated/allowed to tell him? The Noda Bihuda writes that one should tell, but many others disagree. (Better for him to sin unknowingly.)